# Regarding mistake while getting bitmap from the mipmap folder

Tags: android

I have included demo project in my visual studio. But It is showing me error in the following statments. I have copied images and past into the mipmap as well.
Please, can any one check what is the mistake and guide me as well. Thank you in advance.

```
  Bitmap fuelbar= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), );//Bitmap image gets the fuel image from the resources folder
    Bitmap blastCraft = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.explosion);//Bitmap image gets the explosion image from the resources folder
   Bitmap thruster = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thruster);//Bitmap image gets the small thruster image from the resources folder
        Bitmap main_flame = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.main_flame);//Bitmap image gets the main flame image from the resources folder
```

Comment: can not resolve R.drawable.thruster

Comment: I think cause of the error is previously I had give project name com.abc and now I am giving com.xyz. Do you think so?

Comment: @  J. Vyas : Yes.. You have changed package name that is why `R` file is not generating..!!

Comment: You can create a  new project with package name `com.xyz` or just delete `build` folder and try to clean and rebuild project.. Plus remove old `R` imports from java files ..!!

Comment: Thank you friend sending me reply. Please, could you guide me where can I find it in eclipse build folder

Answer (score 6):

What folder you placed your bitmaps ? drawable or mipmap or both ?

If you placed in mipmap folder, you should change your code to:

```
Bitmap blastCraft = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.explosion);//Bitmap image gets the explosion image from the resources folder
Bitmap thruster = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.thruster);//Bitmap image gets the small thruster image from the resources folder
Bitmap main_flame = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.main_flame);//Bitmap image gets the main flame image from the resources folder
```